# Android chat application emoji's issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, chat

I am working on Android chat application. Now I want to send emoji's in my chat module. How can i implement  emoji' in chat application? Please guide me for this app. If there is any API for this app then also suggest me. Thanks

```
  public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new GetSingleChat(Chat_Detail_Single.this).execute(friend_id);

                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                    }
                }
            });

        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 1000, 1000);

} 

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btncamera:
            Dialog_Manager.chooseImage(Chat_Detail_Single.this, "singlechat");
            break;
        case R.id.img_back:
            timer.cancel();
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.btnsend:
            String message_ = edt_mes.getText().toString();
            if (message_.replace(" ", "").length() == 0) {

            } else {
                edt_mes.setText("");
                new  Send_chat_message(Chat_Detail_Single.this).execute(SharedPref.getUserID(this), friend_id, "mes", message_);

            }
            break;

    }
} 
      public static void get_chat_data(List<Chat_prop> fetch_chat) {
    MyCustomList.clear();
    MyCustomList.addAll(fetch_chat);

    try {
        if (adptor == null) {

            adptor = new Single_Chat_Adap(activity,
                    MyCustomList);
            Chat_Detail_Single.listView.setAdapter(adptor);
            Chat_Detail_Single.listView.setSelection(MyCustomList
                    .size() - 1);
            lastCount = MyCustomList.size();
        } else {

            if (lastCount != MyCustomList.size()) {
                lastCount = MyCustomList.size();
                adptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Chat_Detail_Single.listView
                        .setSelection(MyCustomList.size());

            }


        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
       @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    try {

        if (requestCode == Dialog_Manager.Gallery_Intent
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            File direct = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Fun You");
            if (!direct.exists()) {
                if (direct.mkdir())
                    ;
            }
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            capturepath1 = direct.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + time + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(capturepath1);
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            imagePath = getPath(selectedImage);
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            Uri contentUri = selectedImage;
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 1000);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 1000);
            cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 3);

        } else if (requestCode == Dialog_Manager.Camera_Intent
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            File direct = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Fun You");
            if (!direct.exists()) {
                if (direct.mkdir())
                    ;
            }
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            capturepath1 = direct.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + time + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(capturepath1);
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            File photos = new File(imagePath);
            Uri selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(photos);
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            Uri contentUri = selectedImage;
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 1000);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 1000);
            cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 3);

        } else if (requestCode == 3) {
            try {
                Bitmap thumbnail = null;
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    thumbnail = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    Bitmap bm = thumbnail;
                    bm = ExtraMethods.decodeFile(capturepath1);
                    bm = ExifUtils.rotateBitmap(capturepath1, bm);
                    // new Uplaod_image().execute(capturepath1);
                    new Send_chat_message(Chat_Detail_Single.this).execute(SharedPref.getUserID(this), friend_id, "image", capturepath1);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    if (uri == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return uri.getPath();
}
```

Comment: Just sometime back answered it here this shall help you, Question author has also mentioned library too

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific api available to implement and send emojis. You can achieve this using ImageSpan objects. The TextViews and EditTexts use Spanned/Spannable objects to store the entered text content, not just mere Java Strings. On these Spanned/Spannable objects you can define spans for sections on the text that modifies the way that those sections are shown. So you can display images in place of certain sections.

Check the [docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html)

Also, I found a [blog](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-add-smileyemojis-in-edittext.html), it might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks ok i will check

Comment: upvote and accept answer if the information is helpful to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

[This Library](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon) is all you need to implement `Emojicons`. Just don't forget to change your `TextView`s and `EditText`s to this Library's `EmojiconTextView`s and `EmojiconEditText`s respectively.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks how i can add these library in my projoect as am using android studio

Comment: Download this library and import it in Android Studio as a Module.
Then in your project's build.gradle file, add dependency like this..

`dependencies {
    compile project(':ImportedProjectName')
}`

Comment: its showing error while import module that is -: Specify location of gradle or android Eclipse project

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode emoji before upload. 
in this way you encode emoji to UTF code

```
try {
                String mystring = URLEncoder.encode(strComments, HTTP.UTF_8);
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", mystring));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

for decoding

```
enter code here


try {
            String Title = URLDecoder.decode(comment, "UTF-8");
            holder.tvComment.setText(Title);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```