# how to handle smiley in android using unicode character

Tags: android, chat, emoticons

I am working on an Instant Messaging App .Its working fine .I have added emoticons in my application using   compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.3' library .When i am selecting an emoji from the panel of emoticons ,it is displayed in the view and its Unicode is being sent to server and is stored in the database.Encoding and decoding is done using compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6 library .

**Encoding :**

```
 String message = edMessage.getText().toString().trim();
 String toServer = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(message);
```

**Decoding**

```
String messageReceived = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(unicodeMessageReceived);
```

Now i am getting problem in sending pattern like :-),:( .Means if i send :-) ,its corresponding image should be displayed .At this time it is shown as it is .How can i handle patterns here ?How can i view an icon corresponding to a pattern like :-) and store its unicode in database?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736844/android-chat-application-emojis-issue/34736936#34736936) for your answer

Comment: @GaganSingh ,i followed the link provided by you.Still i am not able to understand how to handle the pattern like :-) .Can u please suggest me more references ?Do i need to do some changes in the library which i am using to handle emotions ?